# I want to fetch values from a single column and set these values to a pojo class

Tags: java, drools

I am setting the values to a pojo class to use it in a rule template file.
But I am getting same value in the generated drl.

```
PreparedStatement ps1=cn.prepareStatement("select Tax_MOK_Code from tax_msf_class");
ResultSet rs1=ps1.executeQuery();
while(rs1.next())
{
    p.setMoc1(rs1.getInt("Tax_MOK_Code"));

}
```

Comment: `rs1.getInt("Tax_MOK_Code")` is a variable. You are passing the same variable to `setMoc1` and `setMoc2`.

Comment: PreparedStatement ps1=cn.prepareStatement("select Tax_MOK_Code from tax_msf_class");
    ResultSet rs1=ps1.executeQuery();
    while(rs1.next())
    {
     p.setMoc(rs1.getInt("Tax_MOK_Code"));
    }

Comment: I changed it now, Actually i have to take multiple values and put the same in rule template but i am getting single value.

Comment: I don't see any code to use a "rule template" and create rules from it.

Comment: template header
moc

package org.drools.db;

template "adding drl"

rule "moc @{moc}"
when
    p: Price(moc==@{moc})
then
    p.setTotal()=p.getPrice()*p.getQuantity();
end

rule "moc @{moc}"
when
    p: Price(moc==@{moc})
then
    p.setTotal()=p.getMrp()*p.getQuantity();
end

end template

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with design of your table. If you want to fetch data to 2 fields

```
 p.setMoc1(rs1.getInt("Tax_MOK_Code1"));
 p.setMoc2(rs1.getInt("Tax_MOK_Code2"));
```

It's better to have 2 columns in database and do

```
    select Tax_MOK_Code1, Tax_MOK_Code2 from tax_msf_class
```

Comment: I just want to take multiple values from a single column and assign them to my rule template. I can't use where clause also. I edited my question.

Comment: Also when i am printing the values they are displaying fine but when i set them in the pojo class they get me the same value for all the rules generated.

Answer (score 0):

Create new object of pojo class inside while loop like following example:

```
 while (rs.next()) {
     p = new Person();
     p.setid(rs.getInt("userid"));
 }
```

this will help.